# How to scroll back to vertical Viewpager while having a Horizontal Viewpager as its child?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, touch, swipe

i have a vertical viewpager with Fragment A, and Fragment B. Fragment B has a horizontal viewpager with 3 pages, but there i have a problem: when i am at page 2 or 3 inside Fragment B, i can't scroll vertically to return to fragment A, i can do it only from page 1. i don't know where the problem is, as the 3 pages are almost the same.

Here's my VerticalPager code:

```
public class VerticalPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // The majority of the magic happens here
    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
    // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
            // This page is way off-screen to the left.
            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
            view.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

            //set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { // (1,+Infinity]
            // This page is way off-screen to the right.
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
 */
private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
```

}

Comment: Hmm your view sounds really confusing and prone to bugs. Why not swap one of the view pagers for a recycler view?

Comment: @billynomates, i was using a modified viewpager (from horizontal transformed to vertical) and it had problems, but i found out about a library on github and it works perfect, thanks anyway

Comment: @DuliNini Could you share the library?

Comment: @StefanSprenger I really don't remember what library was, but the best approach would be to create/look for a custom viewpager that is extending ViewGroup and not the native Viewpager, and you could use a boolean and onInterceptTouchMotion in order to enable and disable swiping if you need to

Comment: @DuliNini ok thanks.